# How to use SVG DOM in Python

Tags: python, dom, svg

This question may sounds dumb, but I can't manage to find a correct answer on my own.
I am trying to use the [SVG DOM interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#DOMInterfaces) in my python script. I would like to use [getComputedTextLength](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getComputedTextLength) but I can't find how even if I firstly thought it would be available thanks to modules or a packages like python-svg or something like that.
I am sure there is something I miss, but I can't find what.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

EDIT: I forgot to talk about what my script actually does. It's a Python script used to generate a SVG file from data grabbed on the Internet. My script needs to write texts and repeat them all along a path. Also, as I know the exact length (in pixels) of the path I need to know the length of the text in order to repeat it only what I need to. That's why a method like getComputedTextLength would be helpful.

Comment: Note that getComputedTextLength will return values specific to the font that is used (so if a viewer picks different font then it can make a big difference).

Comment: I read about the specific font, but I have full control on what font, size and properties will be used in the SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://www.gnu.org/software/pythonwebkit/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. DOM is one thing and calling browser's function is other thing. I only saw Python module which help you to create tree structures like HTML or SVG but they don't provide any other additional functionality. (Btw., last time I look even browsers had problems correctly computing `getComputedTextLength` but that was some time ago...)

You could try better luck with [fonttools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fonttools/).